# What could be the reason for this error during build - 'undefined symbols for architecture i386"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, import

It's the first time I am working with the location services and I am hitting this linker error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager"

I had added `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>` and added the following lines in the `viewDidLoad`

```
 CLLocationManager *manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
manager.delegate = self;
[manager startUpdatingLocation];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
    UIAlertView *servicesDisabledAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Services Disabled" message:@"You currently have all location services for this device disabled. If you proceed, you will be asked to confirm whether location services should be reenabled." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [servicesDisabledAlert show];
    [servicesDisabledAlert release];
}
[manager release];
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to edit the question title to be more descriptive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resolve Undefined Symbols error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804510/how-to-resolve-undefined-symbols-error)

Comment: @Josh Caswell: My bad :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add CoreLocation framework to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Core Location framework is linked to your project before building.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to add the framework to your project under the build phases? Here... [How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)